# Migration from js to ts editor issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to migrate my code from java script to type script and using Visual Studio Code as editor.
When I rename the files from js to ts in my project, I do not see any suggestions / warnings (usually underlined red color - say for example variable type not declared in origianl JS file).

Currently I am compiling the ts code manually and fixing the errors but is there any preference setting in VS code to detect the errors directly instead of compiling and checking ?

The tsconfig.json is:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you'll most likely have to create a tsconfig.json file for your project where you specify your project's setup. That will also allow VSCode to give you more info.

Comment: @toskv I do have the tsconfig.json and tslint.json, but I am not sure what is the rule that needs to be added for parameter / variable declarations in tslint and return types for functions.

Comment: can you share your tsconfig.json file? :) It might be that because of your configuration the editor doesn't see those things as errors. :)

Comment: @toskv below is my tsconfig.json contents: ''{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es6"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
} ''

Comment: Awesome. You should make an answer out of that so people that read this in the future know what to do. :)

Comment: Added the below type definition rule to tslint.json file to get this reflected in VS code editor:  "typedef": [true, "call-signature", "parameter", "member-variable-declaration"] - That solved the issue.

Comment: Make an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Added the below type definition rule to tslint.json file to get this reflected in VS code editor: "typedef": [true, "call-signature", "parameter", "member-variable-declaration"] - That solved the issue.